# Missing data between Logstash and ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to parse IIS error XML files with Logstash, and then store those errors in Elasticsearch and display in Kibana.

Here is my logstash.conf file:

```
input 
{
    file{
        path => ["C:/inetpub/logs/FailedReqLogFiles/*/*.xml"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        # filter is not thread safe, so have to move the multiline into the input
        codec => multiline{
            #pattern => "^</failedRequest>"
            pattern => "^<\?xml version"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
            max_lines => 12000
        }
        sincedb_path => "C:/Users/ss/Source/elk/logstash/bin/.sincedb"
    }
}

filter{
    xml{
        store_xml => "false"
        source => "message"
        target => "EVENT"
        xpath => [
          "/failedRequest/@url", "url",
          "/failedRequest/@appPoolId", "appPoolId",
          "/failedRequest/@verb", "verb",
          "/failedRequest/@statusCode", "statusCode"
        ]
    }    
}

output 
{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["100.202.191.77:9200"]
        index => "testserver-logstash"   
        flush_size => 1     
    }
    stdout 
    {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    file{
        path => "C:/Users/ss/Source/elk/logstash/bin/test.log"
    }
}
```

The log file directories are:

```
C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC3
C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC4
C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC5
```

And the log files included in these dirs are: fr000001.xml, fr000002.xml, fr000003.xml, fr000004.xml and so on.

The structure of the xml files is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="https://aaa.bbb.com:443/ddd.aspx" 
               siteId="3"
               appPoolId="aaa.bbb.com" 
               processId="15168"
               verb="GET" 
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-0200-0080030000FF}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500" 
               triggerStatusCode="500"
               timeTaken="368584"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">blablabla
</Event>
</failedRequest>
```

The problem I got is: there are 13 xml log files in total. I can see the logstash output print the parsed xml of all these 13 files correctly in the stdout and test.log, however, in the Kibana, I can only see the data from 4 of the 13 xml files, and the rest 9 files are missing.

I am new to the ELK stack and really got stuck here. Hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked elasticsearch logs? Perhaps it's spitting some error messages out for you.,

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Thanks for the help. I think I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I commented off the line and it looks like the logstash works.

```
 flush_size => 1
```